# How to convert data to JPEG format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, jpeg, nsimage

I have this code:

```
NSImage * strImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:ImageFilePath] ;
NSData *imageData = [strImage TIFFRepresentation];
```

What I require is to convert imageData into JPEG format. I want this to work the same as `QImage save()` does.

So that you can see how `save()` works, I will give you a link:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qimage.html#save

Please help me.

Comment: yes I am asking a new question :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From CocoaDev... If you do anything with the `NSImage` after creating it:

```
NSData *imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];
NSNumber *compressionFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9];
NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:compressionFactor
                                         forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
imageData = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];
[imageData writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

If you don't really do anything else with the `NSImage` before:

```
NSArray *representations = [myImage representations];
NSNumber *compressionFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.9];
NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:compressionFactor
                                         forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
NSData *bitmapData = [NSBitmapImageRep representationOfImageRepsInArray:representations 
                                       usingType:NSJPEGFileType 
                                       properties:imageProps];    
[bitmapData writeToFile:filename atomically:YES];
```

Comment: But what a waste of time; you're getting the TIFF representation of an image, but then immediately creating an image rep from that! If your source image already has a bitmap representation, use that.

Comment: What can I do if I want reverse of this,that means from JPEG format data into NSImage Data???

Comment: @Greshi: Asking a new question? ;)